# Add extra fields to existing json schema and generate c# class on fly

Tags: c#, json, schema, pipeline

I'm trying to find the solution to add extra field to the existing json schema in a new json schema file, and generate them in github pipeline and the project can use them. But I'm not sure how to do it. for example, the existing schema below:

```
  {
    type: 'object',
    required: [ 'product' ],
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
      productName: {
      enum: [ 'product1', 'product2', 'product3' ],
      },
      price: { type: 'int' },
  },
};
```

But know I want to add more fields in properties in additional json, how do I do it? for example I need `product quantity` now, so I can compile two json schema and form one complete class. Also is it possible to reference definition from other schema or I always have to define them respectively.

Very much appreciated if you could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used js and Lodash to merge two scheme files into one, it works like magic.

```
const _ = require("lodash");

const schema = require('./schema.json');
const extention = require("./extentions.json", 'utf-8');
var newschema = _.merge(schema, extention);
const fs = require('fs') 
fs.writeFile("./newschema.json", JSON.stringify(newschema, null, 4), (err) =>
{
    if (err) throw err;
});
```